# .NET Core/Standard .csproj file, embedding license file without it being added to a project using the package?

Tags: .net-core

The past couple of days I've been getting warnings when compiling my .NET Standard/Core projects:

> NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(202, 5): [NU5125] The 'licenseUrl' element will be deprecated. Consider using the 'license' element instead.

To fix this, I switched to using `<PackageLicenseFile>...</PackageLicenseFile>` instead of `<PackageLicenseUrl>...</PackageLicenseUrl>`.

However, in order for this to work, I have to add the license file to my package (naturally), but it gets added to the `content` and `contentFiles` directory, which means that a project using this package gets the license file added to it.

Is there a way to embed the license file so that `PackageLicenseFile` works correctly, without adding the license file to projects using the package?

This is the section I added to the .csproj file in order to embed the license file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\LICENSE" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The output package structure:

```
_rels
package
lib
contentFiles
 +- any
  +- netstandard2.0
   +- LICENSE
content
 +- LICENSE
```

Could I, for instance, add it to a separate folder inside the package, other than `content`?

Comment: Since my license is a standard MIT license I managed to get rid of the embedded file by switching to `<PackageLicenseExpression>MIT</PackageLicenseExpression>`, I'll let the question stand though if anyone has a useful answer.

Answer (score 7):

The recommended way of packing a licence file with the package is

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PackageLicenseFile>LICENSE.txt</PackageLicenseFile>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="LICENSE.txt" Pack="true" PackagePath="$(PackageLicenseFile)"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

But also there now is `PackageLicenseExpression` which can be used as an alternative to license files / URLs as you have mentioned in your comment.

See NuGet's wiki entry [Packaging License within the nupkg](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Packaging-License-within-the-nupkg) for more details.

Comment: What if you want to link to a license instead of embedding a file?

Comment: This is the answer. Stated in the Microsoft docs as I subsequently found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packing-a-license-expression-or-a-license-file